# how to enable previous button of jQuery steps count 1?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

> I want to enable/show previous button for only one tab.

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-steps/1.1.0/jquery.steps.min.js" integrity="sha512-bE0ncA3DKWmKaF3w5hQjCq7ErHFiPdH2IGjXRyXXZSOokbimtUuufhgeDPeQPs51AI4XsqDZUK7qvrPZ5xboZg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

if ($('#example-basic').length > 0)
                $("#example-basic").steps({
                    headerTag: "h3",
                    bodyTag: "section",
                    transitionEffect: "fade",
                    autoFocus: true,
                    saveState: true,
                    titleTemplate: "#title#",
                    labels:
                    {
                        finish: "Next",
                    },
                    
                    onFinished: function () {
                   
                    }
                });
```

```html
<div class="container">
                <div class="row" id="mytab">
                    <div class="col-xl-12">
                        <div id="example-basic">                           
                            <h3>
                                <span class="wizard-icon-wrap"><i class="ion ion-md-podium"></i></span>
                                <span class="wizard-head-text-wrap">
                                    <span class="step-head">tab</span>
                                </span>
                            </h3>
                            <section>
                                @Html.Partial("Partialview")    
                            </section>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
     </div>
```

It count section tag and decided steps . but I only want to use one and need that previous button to show

Comment: count that is section tag I want to use once. and I want to enable previous button and want to perform redirect  action on that previous button.